# IRF7821: is one of them fake?

Tags: transistors, mosfet

[image]

Left looks like genuine (logo), right looks like fake. Is it, really?

Edit: this part is expected to be [IRF7821](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/mosfet/12v-300v-n-channel-power-mosfet/irf7821/).

Comment: I've seen a lot worse discrepancies in marking that the manufacturer claims are both original. But, then again, what chip supplier is going to admit to their parts being counterfeited - nobody would trust what they had and would look for alternatives. It's a big problem in the industry that is unfortunately, too played down IMHO.

Comment: Different assembly sites ('H' vs 'G' on the end of the 1st line) may have slightly different processes or machinery to do the markings.

Comment: De-cap them and compare the internal dies. I did that once with some Sanken power transistors and sure enough, the "fakes" had 60% less die area.

Comment: @Andy If it were one of our chips, my company would certainly want to know, so that we could investigate and take action if it is a problem from any of our supply chain. (And Maxim has posted about the counterfeiting issue publicly before, so I feel I can say at least this much.) As a first step I’d recommend contacting IR applications / customer service and ask them to verify the device markings are valid. Looks like a date code and lot code, they should be able to validate the parts based on that.

Comment: Tell that to ON semiconductor @MarkU. They took nearly 4 months to identify a simple Fairchild TVS and finally got back to me after I really pestered them to say it was one of theirs. Nearly 5% of them out of a batch were faulty and the markings were very dodgy but they said it was one of theirs and gave me zero confidence in them as a honest company in this respect. ON semi, should you be reading this, shame on you.